# Python: Create a sublist for each element & its subelement

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I am working on a project to extract text from pdf.

After extracting texts and assigning tags to each header & paragraph, I want to add their index to a new list to locate each article.

Here is the sample list:

['p',
'',
'',
'header',
'p',
's',
'p',
'',
'',
'p',
's',
'',
'',
'header',
'p',
'p',
's',
'',
'p',
's',
'',
'header']

1. Loop through the list and create a list of lists containing an article-index for each list
2. Each article has a header and several elements such as p, s
   e.g.

```
article-index = [[article1], [article2], [article3]]
article-index = [[header, p, s, p, p], [header, p, p], [header, p, p, s]]
```

3. My initial approach was to get the position of each header using the function below to find the range between the two headers. Then figure out the position of other tags and ignore the empty strings.

```
def get_position(list_, tag):
    #convert list to an array
    array = np.array(list_)
    #return an array of position of searched item
    index = np.where(array == tag)[0]
    return index
----
get_position(list, 'header')
----
array([3, 13, 31])
```

Output:

```
articles_index = [[4,5,6,9,10], [13,14,15, 16, 18, 19], [21]]
```

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I am really not sure what you want to make this answerable please try can create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Nath I have reformulate the question. Let me know if it is clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this solutions might help you out:

Solution 1:

```
import copy

a=['p', '', '','header', 'p', 's', 'p', '', '', 'p', 's', '', '','header', 'p', 'p', 's', '', 'p', 's', '', 'header']

b=[]

# Now wanted to create a sub-list after the "header" string. b=[[header, p, s, p, p], [header, p, p], [header, p, p, s]]

for j in range(len(a)):
    try:
        index_remover=a.index('')
        del a[index_remover]
    except:
        pass
a_copy=copy.copy(a)
index=0
indexes=[]
for k in a:
    # all instace finder
    if k=='header':
        indexes.append(index)
    index+=1
for j in range(len(indexes)):
    try:
        b.append(a[indexes[0]:indexes[1]+1])
        del indexes[0]
    except:
        pass
```

Solution 2:

```
a=['p', '', '','header', 'p', 's', 'p', '', '', 'p', 's', '', '','header', 'p', 'p', 's', '', 'p', 's', '', 'header']
b=[]

for j in range(len(a)):
    try:
        index_remover=a.index('')
        del a[index_remover]
    except:
        print(Exception)
    
for i in a:
    index_finder=a.index('header')
    b.append(a[0:index_finder-1])
    del a[0:index_finder+1]
    
 print(b)
```